# what is the linux boot param "memmap" equivalent in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, kernel, linux-kernel

In linux kernel, there is an option to reserve a portion of system ram i.e
memmap=512M$2G (boot param)   Here 512M starting from 2G would be reserved and not available to OS

What is the equivalent in freebsd ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override hw.physmem at /boot/loader.conf to any value below actual memory size. There is no real alternative to create holes in address space on boot.